# In django's transaction, result of query won't change after update operation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using Django1.8 with mysql database. database isolation level is 'repeatable-read'.
My code looks like:

```python
@with transaction.atomic():
    SomeModel.objects.create(key='aaa') # insert record
    insertedRecord = SomeModel.objects.get(key='aaa') # try to fetch inserted record
```

The problem I encountered is, the `SomeModel.objects.get(key='aaa')` line will throw a `DoesNotExist` exception, which means this query can't see the change made by previous create operation.

Did I miss something here?

Comment: You can use `insertedRecord = SomeModel.objects.create(key='aaa')` potentially.

Comment: Thx. But I just can't figure out why this happens? Also in practice, the atomic block can contains several function calls, and result of `create` won't be directly available.

Comment: repeatable-read guarantees that the same query returns the same result, (I'm not sure whether that is true within a connection or within a transaction). So that get query is being run before the row is added somewhere in the transaction or the connection.

Comment: I don't think you've shown enough code to reproduce the behaviour that you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after some digging I think I finally got the answer.
Our project uses Master-Slave database architecture, read and write operations are routed to different database by django's DATABSE_ROUTERS setting. so in the code:

```
@with transaction.atomic():
    SomeModel.objects.create(key='aaa') # insert record, used the master connection
    insertedRecord = SomeModel.objects.get(key='aaa') # fetch record, used the slave connection
```

The code above basically equals to open two connections, one to write record, one to read the record. So the read won't hit unless the write transaction finishes first.

Instead, this code will give me expected result by forcing reading record with master:

```
@with transaction.atomic():
    SomeModel.objects.create(key='aaa') # insert record, used the master connection
    insertedRecord = SomeModel.objects.using('master').get(key='aaa') # fetch record, force using master connection. Say `master` is alias for master connection
```